# How do you prove a ring homomorphism is onto using the range and kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

The problem is:

> Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring and $a \in A$. If $a^2 = a$, prove that the function $\pi_a(x) = ax$ is a homomorphism from $A$ into $A$. Show that the kernel of $\pi_a$ is $I_a$, the annihilator of $a$. Show that the range of $\pi_a $ is $\langle a\rangle$. Conclude by the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem that $A/I_a\cong\langle a\rangle$.

I'm stuck on the last step. How has $\pi_a$ been shown to be onto/surjective by the above steps?

The question is CH19-D3 from
Pinter, Charles C. "A book of abstract algebra. Reprint of the second (1990) edition." (2010).

Comment: $\pi_a$ need not be surjective. But it is always surjective onto its image...

Comment: @JonasLinssen Could you be a bit more specific? The definition of FHT I'm working with is "Let f : A->B be a homomorphism from a ring A **onto** a ring B and K be the kernel of f. Then B is isomorphic to A/K." So I thought f needed to be onto to use the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using your definition we can modify $\pi$ as follows $ \pi : A \to \langle a \rangle $ then $\pi$ becomes onto and then you can use your theorem about $A/\ker \pi$.
Observe this shows that for any homomorphism $\phi : A \to B$ we have $$ A/\ker\phi \cong Im \phi $$

Comment: Thank you I think I finally get it now. I'm new here but I'll update when I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the word *onto* is often used to mean *surjective* and should not be confused with the *codomain / target* of a function. Imo saying *homomorphism from $A$ onto $B$* for a surjective homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ is a very bad habit, as it may easily be confused with the strictly more general notion of *homomorphism from $A$ to $B$*.

To solve the exercise you need to observe / prove the following things:

- The subset $\langle a \rangle = \{ra \mid r\in R\} \subseteq R$ is a ring with unit $a$ (this uses $a^2=a$!). Note that it is **not** a subring (unless $a=1$).
- The function $\pi_a: R \rightarrow R, r \mapsto ra$ has the image $\langle a\rangle\subseteq R$. In fact, restricting the codomain to the image, it defines a surjective ring homomorphism $\overline{\pi_a}:R \rightarrow \langle a \rangle$.
- The kernel of $\overline{\pi_a}$ is the kernel of $\pi_a$, which is the annihilator of $a$.

The isomorphism theorem now tells you that the canonical map $A/\ker{\pi_a} \overset{\cong}{\longrightarrow} \langle a \rangle, [r] \mapsto ra$ is an isomorphism.